# Clearing DropDownList

Tags: c#, winforms

I am building a windows form in C#, that has, among other things, 2 drop down lists: call them List1 and List2. List1 is populated when the program starts up; List2 is populated based on what the user picks in List1. The problem is that I can't clear List2 of old items when a user picks another choice in List1. I tried

```
List2.Items.Clear()
```

and I tried to delete individual items with this loop

```
int count = List2.Items.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    List2.Items.RemoveAt(0);
```

But neither option works.

Comment: What's the source of items in `List2`?  Is it a data bound list?

Comment: This is not enough code for us to help you, we need to see a full **complete** example to assist you. Both of these methods do exactly what they should in any test environment.

Comment: Please, show the code of List1_SelectedIndexChanged.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I solved the problem. Thank you for your help. In my case, the problem was that before I populated the dropdownlist, I added the values to a C# list, CList, and populated it from that list; however, I did not clear CList between sessions.